# Including an Item's Fields in Sitecore Search

Tags: .net, lucene, sitecore, sitecore6

I have a (Lucene) search control which retrieves items from Sitecore's master database if the item's name matches a term passed in.

However I also want the search to include the item's fields, such that if the search term matches within the item's field, the item is returned. How can this be done?

N.B. The item and its fields are displayed on a page within the site, however the search does not match this either.

Comment: Are you using the "new" Lucene approach or the "old" Lucene approach? Alex Shyba has a tool to make using the new Lucene very easy: http://trac.sitecore.net/AdvancedDatabaseCrawler

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using the "old" Lucene approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the text you are searching for is held in a Single-Line Text field, it may be necessary to add the following into your web.config file under `configuration\sitecore\indexes\index\fields` :

```
<type storage="unstored" stripTags="true">single-line text</type>
```